# android putExtra shows null

Tags: android

I am passing data from one `activity` to another but if I print the data in the other `activity`, it shows null.

I used `PutExtra` and `GetExtra`.

in `first acticity`

```
 intent.putExtra(pin,pins);
 System.out.println(pin);
```

In `second Activity`

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 pined=intent.getStringExtra("pins");
 System.out.println(pined);
```

I got a null message when I try to print the data

> 2019-09-05 08:59:09.425 26480-26480/com.example.beachbocI/System.out: null

Comment: what type of varibale is pins?? interger or string or object?

Comment: what is value of `pin`? Use constant keys to put/get values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first activity

```
intent.putExtra("pin",pins);
    System.out.println(pin);
```

In the second activity

```
pined=getIntent().getStringExtra("pin");
 System.out.println(pined);
```

Answer (score 0):

It shoud be like this

```
  intent.putExtra("pin",pins);
  //"pin" means the name of string
  //pins means your value
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass value you should write below

```
    intent.putExtra("pins",pin); //here `pins` is key use it to get your desired value
```

to get your desired value use the same key as below

```
 intent.getStringExtra("pins"); // use same key `pins`
```

Answer (score 0):

So `putExtra` has two params, 1st is a key, second value

`pin` should be `String` key object

`getStringExtra` has one param, it takes a `String` key value, which should be `pin`